# Jquery cross domain ajax request always error

Tags: python, ajax, json, jquery, bottle

I am trying a to create a simple Jquery mobile application. 
My set up is as follows:

1. jQuery client is running on **localhost:9090/myapp**.
2. My server is running on **localhost:9010/paperboy**
3. Since I am on windows, on the server side I am using a simple server creating using "**bottle**" which is a python micro framework.
4. The server returns json on request, which I can clearly see in Chrome or Firefox.
5. I have validated my response and it is a valid JSON.

The problem I am facing is, that I want my client to read the json from the server response.
But since its a crossdomain issue, it is not able to do so.
Here is my ajax code for the client:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:9010/paperboy/toi",
        type:"GET",
        data:$(this),
        dataType:"jsonp",
        //jsonp:"callback",   no support on the server

        success:function(result){
            console.log("ajax result: " + result);
        },

        error:function(e){
            console.log("Error :" + e);
        }
    });
```

and my bottle Server code is:

```
from bottle import route, run, template, response
from paperboy import getToiNews

''' call http://localhost:9010/paperboy/toi in browser'''

@route('/paperboy/:source')
def index(source='All'):
    print "requesting news list for %s" % source
    resultJson = getToiNews()
    response.content_type = "application/javascript"
    return resultJson

run(host='localhost', port=9010)
```

However on running the application I initially was getting "ajax origin policy error" which soon went away once I added the content type to my server.
Now the ajax call goes through without errors, but always invokes the "error" handler. I have tried various combinations but all in vain. One thing I could not figure out is adding jsonp support to my server.
I appreciate any help in this matter and thank you in advance for all the help.
Thanks.

Comment: I have also tried setting content type as "application/json" from the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said it yourself, since it's a cross-origin call, by default it's disallowed by the [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

If you're in control of the server (and you are), you can use [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) to allow the request. That will work on any modern browser. (Though sadly in the case of IE8 and IE9, you'll need a jQuery patch to enable use of the Microsoft-specific `XDomainRequest` object rather than the standard `XMLHttpRequest`; the jQuery team refuse to put it in the library. IE10 finally adds cross-domain handling to `XMLHttpRequest`.)

Alternately, as the response is JSON, you could use the very similar [JSON-P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) instead, which has the advantage of working with all browsers (and without jQuery patches).

Comment: Brilliant!!! Many thanks to you. It worked like a charm. All I had to do was set a header property. Infact it is present in the [bottle docs using the hooks plugin](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/recipes.html). My bad for over looking it.